# Read data from excel in vb6 and put in a datatable

Tags: excel, vb6

Is there any way to read all the data from excel and put it in the datatable or any other container so that i can filter the data based on the conditions required. As shown in attached image i want to get the CuValue of a Partnumber whose status is Success and i want the latest record based on the Calculation date(Latest calculation date). In the below example i want the CuValue 11292 as it is the latest record with status Success..[image]lue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Excel file format - can it be .xls?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems very broad, but you're right to ask because there are many different possibilities and pitfalls.

As you don't provide any sample code, i assume you are looking for a strategy, so here is it.

- In short: create a database, a table and a stored procedure. Copy the
  data you need in this table, and then query the table to get the
  result.

You may use ADO for this task. If it is not available on your machine you can download and install the MDAC redistributable from the Microsoft web site.
The advantage vs. OLE Automation is that you doesn't need to install Excel on the target machine where the import shall be executed, so you can execute the import also server-side.

With ADO installed, you will need to create two Connection objects, a Recordset object to read the data from the Excel file and a Command object to execute a stored procedure which will do the INSERT or the UPDATE of the subset of the source fields in the destination table.

**Following is a guideline which you should expand and adjust, if you find it useful for your task:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim PartNo as String, CuValue as Long, Status as String, CalcDate as Date

' objects you need:
Dim srcConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim dstConn As New ADODB.Connection


' Example connection with your destination database
dstConn.Open *your connection string*

'Example connection with Excel - HDR is discussed below
srcConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=C:\Scripts\Test.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0; HDR=NO;"";" 

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", _
    srcConn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

' Import
Do Until rs.EOF
    PartNo = rs.Fields.Item(0);
    CuValue = rs.Fields.Item(1);
    CalcDate = rs.Fields.Item(6);
    Status = rs.Fields.Item(7);
    If Status = "Success" Then
        'NumSuccess = NumSuccess + 1
        ' copy data to your database
        ' using a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandText = "InsertWithDateCheck"
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        cmd(1) = PartNo
        cmd(2) = CuValue
        cmd(3) = CalcDate
        cmd.ActiveConnection = dstConn 
        cmd.Execute
    Else
      'NumFail = NumFail + 1
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
srcConn.Close
Set srcConn = Nothing
dstConn.Close
Set dstConn = Nothing

'
```

By using a stored procedure to check the data and execute the insert or update in your new table, you will be able to read from Excel in fast forward-only mode and write a copy of the data with the minimum of time loss, delegating to the database engine half the work.

You see, the stored procedure will receive three values. Inside the stored procedure you should insert or update this values. Primary key of the table shall be PartNo. Check the Calculation Date and, if more recent, update CuValue. 
By googling on the net you will find enough samples to write such a stored procedure.

After your table is populated, just use another recordset to get the data and whatever tool you need to display the values.

- Pitfalls reading from Excel:

The provider of your Excel file shall agree to remove the first two or three rows, otherwise you will have some more work for the creation of a fictitious  recordset, because the intelligent datatype recognition of Excel may fail. 
As you know, Excel cells are not constrained to the same data type per-column as in almost all databases.

If you maintain the field names, use `HDR=YES`, without all the first three rows, use `HDR=NO`.

- Always keep a log of the "Success" and "Fail" number of records read
  in your program, then compare these values with the original overall
  number of rows in Excel.

Feel free to ask for more details, anyway i think this should be enough for you to start.

Answer (score -1):

There are lots ways you can do this.
1. You can create an access DB table and import by saving your sheet as can file first, into the access table. Then you can write queries.
2. You can create a sql DB and a table, write some code to import the sheet into that table.
3. You can Write some code in VBA and accomplish that task if your data is not very big.
4. You can write c# code to access the sheet using excel.application and office objects, create a data table and query that data table
Depends on what skills you want to employ to accomplish your task.